# Impersonate feature goes on the page then switches back to user

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using the impersonate feature which works well. However when I want to switch back to the admin user, I get `access denied` and the user does not change. Which means that when we switch back, `symfony` goes to the page and then switches back which doesn't work for me because I want to return back to my `admin/users`.

First question: is it normal that symfony doesn't switch back user then change the page?
Second question: How do I get the behaviour explained (switching user then switching page)?

Comment: Make sure (double check) you follow cookbook entry http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html. When changing back, i normally use link to admin page (your URL `/admin/users`) with added query string `?_switch_user=_exit` It works well (changes user and displays admin page)

Comment: I double checked, `switch_user: true` is good and I handle right the button logout/quit impersonate. IMO, the error comes from sonata